# How to log to an explicit AWS CloudWatch log stream and change it programmatically (Java/Scala/log4j)

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2

I have a daemon in Scala running on EC2 that processes jobs.  For each job I know a (possibly) different log stream I'd like to append messages to.

How can I make a log-stream specific Appender that I can attach to my log4j logger, and change it when my listener moves on to the next job?

Answer (score 1):

This type of integration is blended of different things like AWS Java API, Log4J API, and AWS Cloud Watch configurations.

You can achieve that by implementing a [customized log4j appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html).
An example you may leverage from github is the [following link](https://github.com/speedwing/log4j-cloudwatch-appender).

The idea is to add the log4j appender class to your source project and use it with your log4j library. The appender will use [AWS CloudWatch API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch.html) to append the logs for a specific [log stream and log group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html) that you need to create on AWS account.

Example: [CloudwatchAppender.java](https://github.com/speedwing/log4j-cloudwatch-appender/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/speedwing/log4j/cloudwatch/appender/CloudwatchAppender.java)

Every log your program creates will send a [cloud watch event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-send-events.html).